# Word for "taking action without diplomacy or discussion"

Tags: single-word-requests

Word for "taking action without diplomacy or discussion"

I am looking for something along the lines of "assert" or "overrule," without a negative connotation - perhaps something along the lines of "taking action into one's own hands" but in a catchy, one-word verb.

The context is the title of a card in a cooperative card game that essentially enables the player to skip deliberation. This can be used to make decisions that are good or bad, but does not imply dissent from the group.

Comment: Please include some context and an example sentence or two where the word or phrase would be used. http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Comment: @Rathony Context added.

Comment: Asking us to help you choose a title is probably Off Topic (who's to say what's the "best" suggestion?). But consider ***preemptive, unilateral***, etc.

Comment: Agree with **Unilateral Decision**

Comment: How about **Executive Order**? it's not a verb but the intent is clear.

Comment: **Make it so!** http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9695/whats-the-origin-of-picards-signature-phrase-make-it-so describes its use in Star Trek by Jean-Luc Picard.

Comment: @k1eran It actually is a space-themed game, so that little Easter egg might be appreciated...

Comment: You need a one-word verb.  I will coin one for you to use in the context of the game.  It is based on "make a snap judgment".  I chose this because "snap" sounds snappy and upbeat.  So, the verb I propose for your game is "snap".  Example: "I am going to ***snap*** Mr Spock onto Planet M.  I think this will benefit everyone."

Answer (score 0):

In context of the card game, 'Affirm' describes taking action, does not bring forth negative connotations and presupposes volition.

Comment: Can you give some references for this?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I'm not sure I understand you, which is perhaps linked to my conception of the purpose of the site.  Do you want me to reference 'Affirm', as in linking it to an online dictionary?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it, a link to a dictionary would give your answer greater credibility and would add strength to your argument. Nevertheless, it might not be worth it as the question is off topic.